# How to add an interval to a date/time stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

I'm writing a bash script on a Fedora 27 machine. This script runs a Python program at intervals, displaying occasional progress messages. It's working except for a line that adds an interval to a time **stored in a variable**.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here's a minimal version of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

next_run_dat=${1}
echo -n 'Next run will be at: ';echo ${next_run_dat}

now_dat=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo -n 'The time is now: ';echo ${now_dat}

while [[ ${now_dat} < ${next_run_dat} ]]
do
    sleep 10
    now_dat=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
    echo -n 'The time is now: ';echo ${now_dat}
done

while true
do
    echo 'This line represents a run.'
    sleep 5

    # ==> PROBLEM LINE BELOW <==
    next_run_dat=$(date -d "${next_run_dat} + 25 seconds" +'Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    echo -n 'Next run will be at: ';echo ${next_run_dat}

    now_dat=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
    echo -n 'The time is now: ';echo ${now_dat}

    while [[ ${now_dat} < ${next_run_dat} ]]
    do
        sleep 5
        now_dat=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
        echo -n 'The time is now: ';echo ${now_dat}
    done
done
```

And here's the output from running the minimal version:

```
$ bash control_bash_minimal.sh '2018-07-23 09:38:00'
Next run will be at: 2018-07-23 09:38:00
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:37:36
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:37:46
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:37:56
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:38:06
This line represents a run.
date: invalid date ‘2018-07-23 09:38:00 + 25 seconds’
Next run will be at: 
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:38:11
This line represents a run.
Next run will be at: Y-07-23 09:38:41
The time is now: 2018-07-23 09:38:16
^C
```

Thanks very much in advance for any help with this problem.

Comment: Because you are missing an '%' in that date command. Should be `date -d "${next_run_dat} + 25 seconds" +%'Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: The minimal version of this question would be "Why isn't `2018-07-23 09:38:06 + 25 seconds` a valid date/time for `date -d`?

Comment: @marekful That's a trivial output problem, but doesn't produce the "invalid date" error.

Comment: For that, use ISO 8601 date format. There should be a 'T' between date and time part, no spaces around it.

Comment: It still doesn't work with T; are you trying any of your suggestions?

Comment: @chepner should we edit this question and update it to your proposal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**note:** this is more an extended comment to [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480905/8344060)

---

From the manual of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items):

> **Combined date and time of day items**
>   The ISO 8601 date and time of day extended format consists of an ISO 8601 date, a ‘T’ character separator, and an ISO 8601 time of day. This format is also recognized if the ‘T’ is replaced by a space.
>
> In this format, the time of day should use 24-hour notation. Fractional seconds are allowed, with either comma or period preceding the fraction. ISO 8601 fractional minutes and hours are not supported. Typically, hosts support nanosecond timestamp resolution; excess precision is silently discarded.

Sadly enough they make no mention of whether or not a time-zone should be included.

Trying to disentangle the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/date.c?h=v8.30) and the used [GNUlib](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/parse-datetime.y) gives me the feeling that [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480905/8344060) is correct. The double usage of the sign brakes the date parser. To be more correct, it assumes that the first number after `+` or `-` is a time-zone offset in hours. Normally, time zones have the format `+HH:MM` or `-HH:MM`, but a single number implements it as `+HH:00`. Evidently, the number has to be smaller than or equal to 24. Example:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 + 9 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 00:38:01 UTC 2018
$ TZ=UTC date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 + 9 2 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 00:38:02 UTC 2018
```

Here, the date is assumed to be in UTC+09:00 and converted to UTC and incremented with a single second and in the second case two seconds.

The example of the OP fails because `+ 25 seconds` is assumed to be UTC+25:00, but this is an invalid time zone:

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 + 25 seconds"
date: invalid date ‘2018-07-23T09:38:00 + 25 seconds’
```

**So, how can we add relative times without falling into the TZ-trap?**

The date parser expects a signed or unsigned number for relative times. Hence we don't really need to add the plus sign and thus we can exploit this for adding time by removing the `+` sign:

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 25 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:38:25 UTC 2018
```

This however only works when you *add* relative time and not when you *subtract* it. But again, we can trick the parser by adding first ZERO seconds or hours or days or whatever to it:

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 - 25 seconds"
date: invalid date ‘2018-07-23T09:38:00 - 25 seconds’
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 0 hours - 25 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:37:35 UTC 2018
```

You can also make use of the keywords `next` and `prev`:

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 next 25 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:38:25 UTC 2018
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 prev 25 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:37:35 UTC 2018
```

If the time zone if not really of importance, simply work in UTC, just add a `Z` to the end of the string.

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00Z + 25 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:38:25 UTC 2018
```

But the easiest of all is to use float-numbers. As time-zones timezones are given as HH:MM a float cannot be interpreted as a time-zone and thus

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 + 25.0 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:38:25 UTC 2018
$ date -d "2018-07-23T09:38:00 - 25.0 seconds"
Mon 23 Jul 09:37:35 UTC 2018
```

Comment: The fact that you can just juxtapose a positive offset is not at all obvious, so this is a little bit more than just a comment on my answer :)

Comment: Updated the answer a bit (@chepner)

Answer (score 3):

The input format uses `+` for two different purposes: to specify a timezone in a timestamp, and to specify a relative increase to a timestamp. In your case, `date` is trying to parse `25 seconds` as a timezone. If you specify an explicit timezone, then you can add an offset:

```
$ date -d "2018-07-23 09:38:00"
Mon Jul 23 09:38:00 EDT 2018

$ date -d "2018-07-23 09:38:00 + 25 seconds"
date: invalid date ‘2018-07-23 09:38:00 + 25 seconds’

# I used a minus sign here to make the output match
# the first example...
$ date -d "2018-07-23 09:38:00-0400 + 25 seconds"
Mon Jul 23 09:38:25 EDT 2018

# ... but positive timezone offsets work too
# (Note that date uses the timezone to parse the
#  input, but converts the result to your local
#  timezone.)
$ date -d "2018-07-23 09:38:00+0100 + 25 seconds"
Mon Jul 23 04:38:25 EDT 2018
```

There may be a way to disambiguate without adding an explicit timezone that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date into EPOCH seconds and add no of seconds using BASH arithmetic like this:

```
dt='2018-07-23 09:38:00'
newdt=$(date -d "@$(( $(date -d "$dt" +%s) + 25))" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

echo "$newdt"
```

```
2018-07-23 09:38:25
```