# add time units to a date without timezone

Tags: bash, date, datetime, timezone

I write these in Linux bash

`date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00" +'%y-%m-%d %T'`

and it prints

`2018-08-21 02:00:00`

But when I write these

```
date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00 +1 hour" +'%y-%m-%d %T'
```

it prints

`2018-08-21 07:30:00` instead of `2018-08-21 03:00:00`

**It adds my timezone to the date**. How can I ignore timezone when I'm adding time units?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an interval to a date/time stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480594/how-to-add-an-interval-to-a-date-time-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: @tripleee yeap I corrected it. (I had copied those from my script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that the `+1` is interpreted as the timezone `UTC+1h`. So it will convert your input date from UTC+1 to your local time-zone and then still add an extra hour to it due to the statement `hour`.

To solve this, you have to get rid of the `+` sign. Here are some possibilities:

```
date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00 next hour" "+%F %T"
date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00 hour" "+%F %T"
```

Or use float numbers:

```
date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00 + 1.0 hour" "+%F %T"
```

For more information on why this is the case, have a look at:
[How to add an interval to a date/time stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480594)

Comment: tnx. I've really got freaked out

Comment: Good answer. Another way to avoid `+` being seen as a timezone offset is to move the relative time phrase away from the end of the time string: `date -d "2018-08-21 +1 hour 02:00:00" +'%y-%m-%d %T'` => `18-08-21 03:00:00`

Comment: @glennjackman This is true, the interpreter works in a very _illogical_ way. I had a look at it for some time. I stoped! Nonetheless, I believe the clearest human-readable form is using float numbers: `date -d "2018-08-21 02:00:00 + 1.0 hour" "+%F %T"`

Comment: @glennjackman The reason your case works is because the date-interpeter does not see the format as an ISO format anymore and so it does not expect a time zone anymore.